# Ratchet: How to connect via PHP to it?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, ratchet

I am running a Ratchet Server

```
$app = new Ratchet\App( 'localhost', 8080 );
$app->route( '/api', new API );
$app->run();
```

It is very easy to connect via JavaScript (and send some messages to the server):

```
_connection = new WebSocket( "ws://localhost:8080" );
```

Now I want the same from PHP (connect and send messages), but I dont know how and I dont find any information in the documentation of Ratchet.

Is it somehow possible? I really need to send messages from PHP to the clients (JavaScript), when there is some event on the server.

**Edit**: I really just need to "fire&forget" some simple message. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

It works a bit wrong.
After connecting to the server, you can send a message from the client to the server and  from the server to the client.

In the Connection Interface is the "**send**" method.
And call onSubscribe or onPublish method you have $topic variable. 
In the $topic is the "**broadcasting**" method.

You need call:

```
  $conn->send($message); or $topic->brodcasting($message);
```

If you need send client message after action on site, use example on [ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/push) (we need install ZMQ)

It works like this:

1. You create server. This server recieve message from users and recieve message from ZMQ.
2. Your site publish on ZMQ message
3. Your server receive message from ZMQ and broadcasting on users

---

Regards Maxim